# Custom Taxonomy template not display

Tags: custom-taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I am having problem when I want to display my taxonomy template.
I have created one custom taxonomy 'Location' for my custom post type 'Project'. Moreover, I have created templates for it as :

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy_name}-{term}.php
taxonomy-{taxonomy_name}.php
taxonomy.php
```

None of them work... I just get my archive-{post_type}.php in all case.

My targetted URLs are :
`mywebsite.com/holliday/united-kingdom/` (Location taxonomy)
`mywebsite.com/holliday/united-kingdom/london` (Location taxonomy child)

I should have messed up or missed something when creating my taxonomy but can't get it right.

Here is my code (register post type and register taxonomy) :

```
// Register Post Type (Holliday)
$capability = 'publish_posts';

$cpt_args = array(
    'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-groups',
    'labels'            => array(
        'name'              => __( 'Holliday', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'singular_name'     => __( 'Holliday', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'add_new'           => __( 'Add Holliday', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add Holliday', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'edit'              => __( 'Edit', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Holliday', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'new_item'          => __( 'New Holliday', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'view'              => __( 'View Holliday', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'view_item'         => __( 'View Holliday', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Holliday', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'not_found'         => __( 'No Holliday found', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'=> __( 'No Holliday found in Trash', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'parent'            => __( 'Parent Holliday', 'mon-plugin' ),
    ),
    'public'            => true,
    'has_archive'       => true,
    'rewrite'           => array(
        'slug'              => 'holliday/%my_project_location%',
    ),
    'supports'          => array('title', 'custom-fields', 'excerpt', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments'),
    'capabilities'      => array(
        'publish_posts'     => $capability,
        'edit_posts'        => $capability,
        'edit_others_posts' => $capability,
        'delete_posts'      => $capability,
        'delete_others_posts'=> $capability,
        'read_private_posts'=> $capability,
        'edit_post'         => $capability,
        'delete_post'       => $capability,
        'read_post'         => $capability
    ),
);
register_post_type( 'my_project', $cpt_args );

// Register Taxonomy (Location)
$cats_args = array( 
    'labels'            => array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Project Location', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Location', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Location', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Location', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Location', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Location:', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Location', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Location', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Location', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Location Name', 'mon-plugin' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Location', 'mon-plugin' ),
    ),
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'public'            => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'has_archive'       => true,
    'rewrite'           => array(
        'slug'              => 'holliday',
        'hierarchical'      => true
    )
);
register_taxonomy( 'my_project_location', 'my_project', $cats_args );
```

EDIT:
If I change my taxonomy slug into something else, I get my taxonomy template working.
Example:

```
 taxonomy slug => "location"  
 mywebsite.com/location/united-kingdom/ => Taxonomy template working !
```

But I want my taxonomy to work with my custom post type. To get my taxonomy template when accessing `mywebsite.com/{custom-post-type}/{taxonomy}/`
But this give me `archive-{custom-post-type}.php` file instead.

Following the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) I expect Wordpress to find me the taxonomy template before the archive template.

Is there something I am missing ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you see your taxonomy in admin page? I you really sure that it was loaded?

Comment: Can you show the code used to register your CPT, as well as the URL you are accessing that is ending up using archive-{post_type}.php? Also, have you visited the permalink settings page since registering the CPT and tax?

Comment: @AntonLukin, Yes I see it, no problem to access my custom post.

Comment: @WebElaine, I visit my permalink page each time I change the code to register my taxonomy.

Comment: I've seen really weird things happen when CPTs or taxonomies are registered with a long name. I would suggest trying something shorter than `my_project_location` - maybe `h_location` - and see if that helps in any way.

Comment: @WebElaine, Nothing changed with short name.

Comment: It looks like you are registering both your CPT and your Taxonomy to use the /holliday/project-location/ URL structure. Whenever there are 2 content types at the same URL, only one of them will win out. You could try `unregister_taxonomy` and then re-register it with a totally different URL just to test out whether or not this is the case, then if so, find a new permalink plan.

Comment: @WebElaine, I did what you said and you are right ! I got my taxonomy templates. But if I follow the [template hirearchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) I expect to get taxonomy template before archive template. My goal is to combine post type and taxonomy, so I don't want to change the slug but follow the template hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you WebElaine for your help ! I figured out a way to solve it.

It looks a bit as you proposed in **Option 2**. Except that I used the filter **`parse_query`**  to change my CPT `'has_archive'` to false when accessing my taxonomy.

Here is the code :

```
function check_taxonomy_query( $query ) {
    if ($query->query['my_project_location'] && !$query->query['my_project']) {
        $query->is_post_type_archive = false;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'check_taxonomy_query' );
```

`my_project_location` and `my_project` are the query vars used for my rewrite rules:

```
$newRules['holliday/?$']    =   'index.php?lang=en&post_type=my_project';
$newRules['holliday/([^/]+)/?$']    =   'index.php?lang=en&post_type=my_project&my_project_location=$matches[1]';
$newRules['holliday/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$']    =   'index.php?lang=en&post_type=my_project&my_project_location=$matches[1]/$matches[2]';
$newRules['holliday/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$']    =   'index.php?lang=en&post_type=my_project&my_project_location=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&my_project=$matches[3]';
```

So in the `check_taxonomy_query` function, I simply check if I am in the case of the 2nd or 3rd line of my rewrite rules. If yes, I turn the post type archive down.

Hope it could help someone ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different solutions if you want to have only the /holliday/project-location/ URL and not separate archive and taxonomy URLs.

**Option 1:**

Use the [`template_include()` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include). I think this code would work but have not tested:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'holliday_template', 99 );

function holliday_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'holliday' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'taxonomy-my_project_location.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

**Option 2** (even simpler):

Tell WP not to give your `holliday` CPT an archive. When you register the post type, just change `'has_archive' => true,` to `false`. That way, when WP looks for content at your desired URL, only the taxonomy archive exists. You will most likely need to use `unregister_post_type()` and re-register it to force the change.